# BLE max write length

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the max write size for a Characteristic in android. In iOS you have a method such as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1620312-maximumwritevaluelengthfortype?language=objc . But it doesn't seems like there's one like this in android.

Thanks

Comment: When you scan for characteristics can't you just read the `characteristic.value` length?

Comment: I do not want to broadcast a value I want to be able to write on specific value per ble device who are neer me

Comment: But when you scan for characteristics within services the characteristic should have a default value. The total number of bytes in the value will be the total number of bytes that can be written to the characteristic - the *max write size*.

Comment: Oh ok thanks will give it a try what I'm doing actually is requestMtu with a high mtu value then substract 3 at the mtu i retrieve on onMtuChanged

Comment: @AdamMitchell just tried when I retrieve my characteristic I call getValue() but it return null